# modulus operation gives negative value in php

Tags: php, modulus

I expects **768** from the following statement. But it echos **-360**. why?

```
echo 1364808202768%1000;
```

UPDATE:

```
#: php -v
PHP 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.17 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Jun 19 2012 01:35:33) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.0.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2008, by Derick Rethans

#: php -r 'echo 1364808202768%1000;'
-360

#: uname -a
Linux tripura 2.6.32-37-generic #81-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 2 20:35:14 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: its working correct i have tested.

Comment: On what PHP version on what system? http://3v4l.org/fIGtV

Comment: Its giving `768` http://codepad.viper-7.com/I0GaM6

Comment: PHP 5.4.7, XAMPP, Windows: I also get `-360`.

Comment: It is worth noticing that when working with large numbers, most noticably using the modulo operator, the results depend on your CPU architecture. Therefore, running a decent 64-bit machine will be to your advantage in case you have to perform complex mathematical operations. Here is some example code - you can compare its output on x86 and x86_64 machines:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because the number exceeds the maximum that the integer type can hold. You can check if an integer is too big like this:

```
var_dump('1364808202768' > PHP_INT_MAX);
```

The built-in function `fmod` is easy to use, and it should be able to handle big numbers:

```
echo fmod('1364808202768', 1000);
```

You can also use one of two common extensions ([GMP](http://php.net/gmp) and [BC](http://php.net/bc)) if, for whatever reason, `fmod` is not available, or if you frequently work with large numbers:

```
// Using the GMP extension
$big = gmp_init('1364808202768', 10);
$val = gmp_strval(gmp_mod($big, 1000));
echo $val;

// Using the BC extension
echo bcmod('1364808202768', 1000);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think thats because its above the int limit, use `fmod(1364808202768,1000);`

Answer (score 2):

You should read about the data types and their range. Use this:-

```
$num = 1364808202768;
echo fmod($num,1000);
```